# Animation in preexecute() method

Tags: android, animation, android-asynctask

I am trying to do an animation (using animation-list in xml) on clicking of a `TextView`. In `OnClick` of the `OnClickListener()`, I am using an `AsyncTask` to do some background operations. So I placed the code to start the animation in the `AsyncTask's` `preexecute()` method. But the animation happens only after the `doInBackground()` completes. Why is that? The animation code in `preexecute()` is as follows

```
protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Drawable current =  mainActivity.textClicked.getBackground();
          if (current instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
              AnimationDrawable btnAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) current;
              btnAnimation.setVisible(true, false);
              btnAnimation.start();
          }
    }
```

Comment: make sure `onPreExecute()` is code or not using log or add `@Override `on top of `onPreExecute`

Comment: onPreExecute() is not using log and yes I do have the @Override annotation.

Comment: i mean put log inside onPreExecute and check logcat you are getting logs or not

Comment: yes it is being logged in the proper sequence after I upgraded to HoneyComb, but still it doesnt happen sequentially (Asynctask doesnt wait for animation to complete, it calls doInBackground() immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, may be you are using .get() method inside ui thread.

Taken from
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101171/android-progress-dialog-in-asynctask-not-showing-up)

Just use the .get() inside a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable current =  mainActivity.textClicked.getBackground();
          if (current instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
              AnimationDrawable btnAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) current;
              btnAnimation.setVisible(true, false);
              btnAnimation.start();
          }
```

Write the above lines before Or After call  `AysncTask`. Because if we are using `AsyncTask` it wont wait there until the task complete.

For more information read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Yes, I tried this also.But the result is not as expected. Not sure of the timing since I have some repetitive tasks in the background - it takes quite sometime - tried to match this with the animation time, but again it doesnt perform the same everytime. What are the other ways to make it happen sequentially? First animation and on-completion then the Async task should begin? Could this be a bug?   Tried on the HoneyComb version also where parallel processing of AsyncTask by multiple threads has been replaced with a single thread, but still the same result? am i missing something here?