# Android: Progress Dialog in AsyncTask not showing up

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am starting the `asynctask` inside a `SherlockListFragment` which was created inside a `SherlockFragmentActivity` as a tab.

I pass the `asynctask` constructor my activity context and initialize the asynctask like this inside `onCreate()`:

```
AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> asynctask = new DownloadFilesTask(getSherlockActivity()).execute(url);
```

The constructor inside the AsyncTask class DownloadFilesTask looks like this:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private SherlockFragmentActivity activity;

public DownloadFilesTask(SherlockFragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }
```

Pre-execute and post execute look like this:

```
protected void onPreExecute(){  
        Log.d("AsyncTask!", "Showing dialog now!"); //shown in logcat
        dialog.setMessage("Retrieving all currently airing anime. Please wait.");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();  
    }
```

.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) { 
    Log.d("AsyncTask!", "Dismissing dialog now!"); //shown in logcat
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

But the progress dialog doesn't show up while all the background work is being done! 
What am I doing wrong here? I think it might be a context problem.

Comment: You should post your code on how (and when) you're executing the AsyncTask. Note: You need to instantiate it and call execute on the UI thread (per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I'm creating the AsyncTask instance in the onCreate of a class that extends SherlockListFragment. How do I call it on the UI thread?

Comment: just for the sake of experiment, drop the SherlockFragmentActivity aspect and just pass in a good ol' Context directly. call your constructor with new DownloadFilesTask(this) and then .execute(url) and see what happens.

Comment: I did this and the dialog now shows up and closes immediately at the end of the execute. I need it to start at the pre-execute, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the problem was fixed thanks to the comment from Mike Repass about passing a plain old context.

As for the dialog not showing up...I was just being stupid because I called a `.get()` after the execute OUTSIDE the AsyncTask which blocks the UI thread. Obviously the dialog is not going to show up that way.

Answer (score -1):

In Java "If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword **super**." Therefore change your onPreExecute() method when you start progress dialog to:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){  
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    Log.d("AsyncTask!", "Showing dialog now!"); //shown in logcat
    dialog.setMessage("Retreiving all currently airing anime. Please wait.");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();  
}
```

Comment: This is from the [AsyncTask source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java): `protected void onPreExecute() {
    }`. A call to super won't do much.