# Showing progressdialog for asynchronous httprequest

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

**Requirement**

Show the 2nd fragment to the user only when `HttpRequest` is complete and valid.

**As of now**

By referring various post from SO, it is learnt that we need to use `AsyncTask` to send `HttpRequest` and we've placed it in a separate `class` file with name `Httpclientrequest.java`

```
public class Httpclientrequest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context mContext;
    public Httpclientrequest(Context context){
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Sending request");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       //perform httprequest
       //return String
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and in my `Fragment1.java` on `clickeventlistener`, I've below things done.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
      Httpclientrequest httpClientRequest = new Httpclientrequest(getContext());
      try {
             Object result = httpClientRequest.execute().get();
             FragmentTransaction ft= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.content,new Fragment2());
             ft.commit();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

With the above way, the `progressdialog` will never show until httprequest is complete and appears and disappears for fraction of second before next `fragment` is loaded. **[When searched for this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120717/2065039)**, we've found that `.get()` on `execute()` blocks the Main UI thread. Now when `get()` is removed, it shows `progressdialog` before `request`, but by then 2nd fragment is loaded, without waiting for request to complete. It is the requirement that based on some condition from response, 2nd fragment has to be shown.

**Question** - How should we actually `await` for the `AsyncTask` along with `ProgressDialog` shown in the screen? Are we going out of track here, which can be done in more simpler way?

Comment: use a interface as callback to detect http request completion,and perform your fragment transaction in that listener onCompletion callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your fragment transaction code in `onPostExecute` in `Httpclientrequest` like this using `.execute();`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        FragmentTransaction ft= context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content,new Fragment2());
        ft.commit();
    }
```

if you are not able to find `getFragmentManager()` than you have to pass `getActivity()` in `Httpclientrequest` constructor and cast context like this

```
FragmentTransaction ft=((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the post, we have used separate class for to make `AsyncTask` common throughout the application and I feel the above approach we have in question isn't going to work well. So, I have followed **[This post here](http://androidlift.info/2015/09/21/android-restful-web-service-with-json-to-insert-data-to-server-mysql-database-using-httpurlconnection-class/)** and hence changed structure accordingly. I am going to accept this answer as this approach would fit in here.. :) Thanks for your time.. :)